# How do we get list of items in a workflow using powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions, workflow

I need to get list of items/pages and all its associated contents in a workflow using the powershell script. Is there any possibility to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3):

You can use something really simple if you not have many items  :

```
    $itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow = Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/media library/*[@__Workflow='{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}']"
    
    foreach ($item in $itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow)
    {
      
            Write-Host " -" $item.ID $item.Paths.FullPath
        
    }
```

If you have huge amount of items I suggest to query in the search indexes.

Comment: I was able to get parent items, now how do I get the children items within the given path in query? Consider I am looping through "sitecore/content/My home"

Comment: $itemsWithMatchingDefaultWorkflow = Get-Item -Path master: -Query "/sitecore/content/My home//*[@__Workflow='{0729C93B-888A-4765-8486-8F1AE86A3894}']" try in this way.

Comment: and have a look here to understand how Sitecore query is working: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/SdnArchive/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.html